# How to get sum of pages under a certain pagenumber style

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, tex-core, page-numbering

I construct an article with three kinds of pagenumber style.

```
- fist part: \pagenumbering{Roman}

- Sencond part: \pagenumbering{arabic}

- third part: \pagenumbering{Alpha}
```

Q1:

How can I get the sum of pages of each part? For example, there are 3 pages in the first part with pagenumber style Roman, and 5 pages in the second part with pagenumber style arabic. The answer to this question will be used in the Q2.

Q2:

In the foot of every page in each part, I'd like typeset the page number like this: `Page\ \thepage\ of\ \totalpages{Roman}`(or arabic, Alpha for related part). I know `@abspage@last`, but it just give a total page number of an whole article. So is it possible to make a macro like `\totalpages{Roman/arabic/Alpha...}` to achieve this? No other packages preferred.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}

\newcommand\totalpages[1]{...}

\begin{document}
part 1:
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\cfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \totalpages{Roman}}
...
part 2:
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\cfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \totalpages{arabic}}
...
part 3: \pagenumbering{Alpha}
\cfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \totalpages{Alpha}}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would that be "Page I of X" or "Page I of 10"?

Comment: Both are all right and preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have added an alternative solution (currently commented out) that gives `Page A of 4` instead of `Page A of D`. It needs some hackery, using LaTeX internals, however.

Here is a solution with an extra macro `\changepagenumbering`. This remembers the last page number of the previous chunk and puts it in a label. It also does a`\newpage`, because changing page numbers mid-page doesn't make sense. Maybe it also works without this `\newpage`. I then use `\pageref` to pick up this number in `\totalpages`. You will need at least one extra LaTeX run to get the numbers correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Start a new page numbering scheme. Remember the number of pages of the
% previous scheme and start a new page (changing page numbering mid-page
% doesn't make sense)
%
\newcommand\previousnumbering{}
\newcommand\changepagenumbering[1]{%
  \label{last-pagenumber-of-\previousnumbering}%
  \newpage
  \renewcommand\previousnumbering{#1}%
  \pagenumbering{#1}%
}
\newcommand\totalpages[1]{\pageref{last-pagenumber-of-#1}}

% If you want the number of pages in decimal use this instead of the above:

% \newcommand\mypagecount{\arabic{page}}
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand\mylabel[1]{\@bsphack
%   \protected@write\@auxout{\let\mypagecount\relax}%
%          {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\mypagecount}}}%
%   \@esphack}
% \makeatother
% \newcommand\previousnumbering{}
% \newcommand\changepagenumbering[1]{%
%   \mylabel{last-pagenumber-of-\previousnumbering}%
%   \newpage
%   \renewcommand\previousnumbering{#1}%
%   \pagenumbering{#1}%
% }
% \newcommand\totalpages[1]{\pageref{last-pagenumber-of-#1}}

\begin{document}
\changepagenumbering{Roman}
\cfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \totalpages{Roman}}
\section{part 1}

\lipsum

\changepagenumbering{arabic}
\cfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \totalpages{arabic}}
\section{part 2}

\lipsum[1-40]

\changepagenumbering{Alph}
\cfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \totalpages{Alph}}
\section{part 3}

\lipsum[10-30]

% end with a dummy one
\changepagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you kindly provide also a solution for ` Page I of 10`?

Comment: That probably would require another package. Is that a problem?

Comment: I prefer a solution non other packages. Or is it possible to get the absolute number of a middle page in article when there are two or more page number styles in it?

Comment: Modern LaTeX has a counter `totalpages`, which is the total number of pages that has yet been output. It can be printed with `\thetotalpages`. However, when you are constructing the footer the current page has not yet been output, so it hasn't been counted yet. So on page 4, the counter is 3. You could use this to do the calculation, `totalpages` - the value at the end of the previous section. But notice: the calculated number must be put is a `\label`-like structure, written to the `aux`-file because it must be used before it has been calculated.

Comment: I have added an alternative solution that gives decimal numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for these solutions!! And does that mean there is no internal macro in modern LaTeX to get the absolute number of a page in article especially when there are two or more page number styles in it?

Comment: In LaTeX you know the page number only when the page is built, not during the processing of the text. That is also true for `totalpages`, which can be considered the absolute page number - 1. But it may be incorrect near the page border. To get it absolutely correct you need marks or labels.

Comment: If there are two or more page number styles in an article, it seems that using of marks and label gives still the relative page number of a middle page, not its absolute page number in the article(the xxth page).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139348/discussion-between-pieter-van-oostrum-and-lyl).

Comment: I'm sorry. I have been trying to go to the chat room but failed. Maybe the reason of web connection or firewall.

Comment: It's just a web page with the link above.

Comment: Yes, I tried many times of the link above. It seems that some firewall block me to access the link.

Comment: What I said was: That's right. You would need special \label-like code to send the absolute page number to the aux file, similar to what I did in my second code.